# PushSharp Vs Signal R

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, pushsharp

I used webApi for create web Service and provide Web services to mobile Android/Apple programmer. I want to send a notifications for mobile when the database has changed. I searched on the internet and found that i can use PushSharp or Signal R. Which is the best option ?

Answer (score 0):

**It is really depends !!**

if you want Notification server for mobile app i think PushSharp is good solution it's built as Push Notification framework for mobile app it is depends on GCM (google cloud messaging API ) it's full free API from google .
I think this task is not for signalR . 
signalR is a framework for building real time apps you can Implement any Scheme like pub-sub .
what i know there is a client implementation for signalr for android called :

- SignalA : URL : github.com/erizet/SignalA

> So if you want to send Notification to Mobile app you can use one of
>   those :

- [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp)
- [PushBots](https://pushbots.com/)

i found pushsharp more reliable . 
and has a big community . 
also you must consider what your mobile app developer good at ??! .

Answer (score 0):

As Khairy said, SignalR and PushSharp do very different things.

SignalR is a real-time web framework. It is best suited to *real time, two-way communication* between a client and a server. It requires that your client application be in constant communication with your server.

PushSharp is a push notification library. It is used to send, well, notifications. The act of sending a push notification to a client is inherently *one way*, and might not happen in real time.

If all you really want to do is send notifications, I see no reason why you wouldn't want to use the right tool for the job. In this case, PushSharp is the right tool for the job.